# Knapsack algorithm with an additional property

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

When there's 1 property, I do understand what's going on in there.
I'm having a problem with understanding knapsack problem when there's more than 1 property.

[image]

I have to write a program that uses knapsack algorithm with a 2 properties. Teacher told us, It has to be done in a 3d array. I can't imagine how would such array look like.

Let's say here's my input:

```
4 3 4 // number of records below, 1st property of backpack, 2nd property  of backpack
1 1 1 // 1st property, 2nd property, cost
1 2 2 // 1st property, 2nd property, cost
2 3 3 // 1st property, 2nd property, cost
3 4 5 // 1st property, 2nd property, cost
```

And the output would look like that:

```
4    // the cheapest sum of costs of 2 records
1 3  // numbers of these 2 records
```

The explanation of output:
2 sets of records fit's into 1'st line of input:

(1) - record number 1 and record number 3

```
  1 1 1
+ 2 3 3
-------
  3 4 4
```

(2) - record number 4

```
  3 4 5
```

Because 1st set of the records is the cheapest (4 < 5), we chose it. Not only I'll have to find out whether such set of records exists, I'll also have to find records I've summed.

But for now, I only need to understand, how will 3d array look like. Could some of You help me out with that and show, layer by layer, just like in my image, how would this look like?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first array.  What is the meaning of the values in the array?

Comment: eg. In backpack with V = 2 and 1 2 items with V=1, you can put there maximally 2x V=1 items. In backpack with V = 3, and with items V=1 and V=1, you can put there maximally both of these items so it's v=2 inside that cell. In backpack with v=3 and items 1,1,2, you can put there maximally 2 items (v=1,v=2) so it gives 3. Values inside the cells is the maximum package of the backpack

Comment: I think your teacher looks for [multiple constraints knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems#Multiple_constraints)

Comment: @Paulina I think I understand.  The columns of your grid are for the current remaining volume (or other property) of the backback.  The rows are for the various items remaining to choose from, sorted in increasing volume order.  Say we had a knapsack of volume 6.  First we add the item of volume 3, leaving a remaining volume of 3.  Then we look in the 3 column, and we would go to the '2' row, since we already used the '3' item, and that cell should read '2', I think.  We add the '2' item, leaving a volume of 1.  In the 1 column, we add the lower '1' item, pack full. Do I have this right?

Comment: yeah :P You are right gmlobdell

Comment: @gmlobdell did you consider writin your comment as an answer?

Comment: 1-You are looking for multiple-constraint knapsack problem. 2-Your first figure has issues. 3-Knapsack problem is solved using dynamic programming, not arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Say you are using a three dimension table: `A[x][y][z]=k`, `x`: sum 1st property; `y`: sum 2nd property; `z`: sum 3rd property; k: minimal cost (maximal reward, which I prefer using reward)

So you iterate over items. Say current item is (p1, p2, p3, reward) (*reward = - cost*). for each `(x,y,z,k)`, your update formula:

```
A[x+p1][y+p2][z+p3] = max(A[x+p1][y+p2][z+p3], A[x+p1][y+p2][z+p3] + reward)
```

If the 1st term on RHS is greater, on slot `A[x+p1][y+p2][z+p3]`, the configuration of knapsack is remain still; otherwise, you update the knapsack by that of `A[x+p1][y+p2][z+p3]` plus the current item.

Hope this cut things clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do something impossible - that's your problem.

When you are adding to the number of dimensions, your items are getting additional properties. So, instead of a left, column side of a table(`prop1`), you have rectangle side(`prop1` x `prop2`) or block side `(prop1` x `prop2` x `prop3`) and so on. But the existing constraints, that define the upper, row side of the table, should have the same number of dimensions. **Not only one dimension!**. So, you will **never** be able to put two-property problem into a 3-dimensional block, you need 4D block instead. 6D block for 3 properties and so on.

Comment: Can you explain what is "additional properties"? The table is to record the best configuration of the knapsack given a cost. It seems you are thinking differently.